# ListView with checkboxes?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

So I'm trying to populate a `ListView` with `Checkboxes`. While my code does populate the `ListView` with the correct number of `Checkboxes`, the text for each textbox is incorrect (it appears to be the raw code for the `Checkbox`). What am I doing wrong?

Result:

[image]

Code for populating a checkbox: (SUBJECTS is an array of strings)

```
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        ArrayList<CheckBox> your_array_list = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
            cb.setText(SUBJECTS[i]);
            your_array_list.add(cb);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<CheckBox> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CheckBox (this, R.layout.cbview, your_array_list );
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

XML code for cbview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`your_array_list.add(cb);`

that line is adding the `CheckBox` object that you create which is why you get the output you do.

Change that to

```
your_array_list.add(cb.getText().toString());
```

this will get the String text that you have added to it with `cb.setText()`

Comment: and what's also important, please don't keep Views in your adapter... and also, we have RecycleView now so please go and read the following tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
I KNOW that this is not a easy answer but help yourself and go learn modern 21st century Android ;-)

Comment: It doesn't work because your_array_list is initialized to be an arraylist of checkboxes, so it can't take in a string.

Comment: I missed that part which is why pelo's comment didn't make sense to me :P Anyway, why is it an Array of Checkboxes? Why can't it be Strings? Or create a "data" class to hold the relevant data and use `ArrayList<YourObject>` and use [MultiChoice](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:choiceMode)

Comment: Ended up changing it to an array of strings, and it works.